# RenderBox was not laid out, Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize' GridView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

when I call this page on my Home page inside of ListView I face this problem, what I want to do is to add some other values like "category" before the Product page inside of my Home page.

can anyone please help me?

Product Page

```
class HomeTab extends StatelessWidget {
  final CollectionReference _productsRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            future: _productsRef.get(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                  ),
                );
              }

         
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                // Display the data inside a list view
                return ListView(children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 500,
                    child: GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      childAspectRatio: .52,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 130.0, bottom: 12.0, left: 5, right: 5),
                      children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
                        final dynamic data = document.data();
                        return ProductCard(
                          price: "\$${data['price']}",
                          productId: document.id,
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]);
              }

              // Loading State
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
         
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is all my code

Comment: Try, Add shrinkWrap : true inside ListView

Comment: No, that did not work

Comment: do you have any other idea